# Find dicts from lists the have the closest value in a faster/better way

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I tried searching for a response to this but could not find one even though i'm sure it must have been asked before. Must not be searching the correct phrases.

My problem is I have two large lists of dicts and am trying to match up dicts in list A to the dict in list B that has the closest value for a particular key, in this case `timestamp`. The timestamps from the dicts may or may not be exactly the same, and I only want to proceed acting on the dict from list A if it has a match from list B with a timestamp value within 15 of it's timestamp. Also the dictionaries are not identical in structure but do both always contain a timestamp key value pair.

First i tried something similar to this:

```
for itemA in ListA:
    closestItemB = min(ListB, key=lambda x :abs(x["timestamp"])-int(itemA["timestamp"))
    if(abs(itemA['timestamp'] - closestItemB['timestamp']) < 15:
        #write info from both dicts to a csv file
```

This was *extremely* slow for large lists. Then I realized the lists are both ordered by timestamp so it should be possible to speed this up significantly

My thought process was on the first loops through search the entire list B for the closest and then next time through only search through a small slice just beyond the last matching listB index. In 99%  of cases the next item form list A matches the one of the next few items from list B. But sometimes they don't and in that case I searched to the end of list B again looking for the closest match, then go back to searching small slices again until the next miss.

```
for itemA in listA:
    closestItemB = min(listB[lastFoundIndex:lastFoundIndex+3, key=lambda x :abs(x["timestamp"])-int(itemA["timestamp"))
    if(abs(itemA['timestamp'] - closestItemB['timestamp']) < 15:
        lastFoundIndex = listB.index(closestItemB)
        #write info from both dicts to a csv file
    else:
        closestItemB = min(listB[lastFoundIndex:len(listB)-1, key=lambda x :abs(x["timestamp"])-int(itemA["timestamp"))
        if(abs(itemA['timestamp'] - closestItemB['timestamp']) < 15:
            lastFoundIndex = listB.index(closestItemB)
            #write info from both dicts to a csv file
```

This is faster than the first iteration, but not by nearly as much as I would have expected. Interestingly it gets slower and slower at finding a match as it runs. I', guessing this might be something to do with the way the list slicing works as i'm not entirely sure what is happening under the hood there.

As you may be able to tell my python isn't the best. I thought of a better way to write the code, but don't know how to write it in a pythonic way.

What i would like to do is search through list B until the sign of the difference in timestamp from list A and list B flips, at the point one of the last two items checked has to be the closest to the list a. Then for the next item in listA i can do the same thing, but starting from the index in list B where I just found a match. This code would replace the following line:

```
closestItemB = min(listB[lastFoundIndex:lastFoundIndex+3, key=lambda x :abs(x["timestamp"])-int(itemA["timestamp"))
```

But I am not sure how to write it.

Or there may be an entirely other way of solving this problem(I find there always is when it comes to python)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How about first sorting the lists of dicts by the timestamp key? Unsorted lists necessarily have to have every item searched every iteration. If they are sorted, they don't. You will know you have your match as soon as the difference between the timestamp comparisons increases instead of decreases. Also, if they are both sorted in the same direction (asc or desc), one would expect that the matches would happen quickly, much more quickly then doing a full list B iteration every single time

Comment: They are sorted by timestamp already. How to do the search until the difference increases instead of decreases is essentially the question I was asking.

Comment: Are the matches between listA and listB 1-to-1? In other words, can an item in listB match more than 1 item in listA?

Comment: we need example data to test answers - I would try a binary search if you show even short 'toy' data with your list structure, make clear which package 'timestamp'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following code? It's using two lists with "timestamp" numbers in them instead of dicts, but using dicts would only slightly 
complicate matters - the algorithm would stay the same.

The idea here is to have two pointers into a and b (ia and ib), and see if the values at ia and ib are close enough to make a match. If they aren't, then if the difference is positive, it means that the value in a is much further ahead than the one in b and ib has to play catchup. If the difference is negative, then it's the other way around and ia has to play catchup.

```
a = [1, 4, 35, 40, 56, 70, 90, 110 ]
b = [3, 20, 39, 57, 62, 84, 100, 150]

ia = 0
ib = 0
while ia < len(a) and ib < len(b):
    delta = a[ia] - b[ib]
    if abs(delta) <= 15:
        print("Found match at ia={} ({}) and ib={} ({})".format(ia, a[ia], ib, b[ib]))
        # Both items are matched, continue with the next ones 
        ia += 1
        ib += 1
    elif delta > 15:
        # we're too far behind in the b list, try to catch up
        ib += 1
    elif delta < -15:
        # too far behind in the a list, try to catch up 
        ia += 1
```

Note that I wasn't sure how to handle cases where two values from one list might match one in the second - for example, both 1 and 4 from the `a` list could match 3 from the `b` list, but the algorithm as presented takes a value out of the race once it is matched to a partner from the other list. You could change that by changing what happens to `ia` and `ib` once a match is found.

The following code finds all possible matches (I think), still with only a single iteration (but doesn't add matches to a candidate list to find the best one:

```
a = [1, 4, 35, 40, 56, 70, 90, 110 ]
b = [3, 20, 39, 57, 62, 84, 100, 150]

ia = 0
ib = 0
while ia < len(a) and ib < len(b):
    delta = a[ia] - b[ib]
    if abs(delta) <= 15:
        print("Found match at ia={} ({}) and ib={} ({})".format(ia, a[ia], ib, b[ib]))
        if delta < 0:
           # there might be a better match yet for the timestamp at ib
           ia += 1
        elif delta > 0:
           # there might be a better match yet for the timestamp in ia
           ib += 1
        else:
           # perfect match, it won't get any better. Move along in both lists
           ia += 1
           ib += 1
    elif delta > 15:
        # we're too far behind in the b list, try to catch up
        ib += 1
    elif delta < -15:
        # too far behind in the a list, try to catch up 
        ia += 1
```

Now if you really needed to find the best (closest) match, your code might look like this:

```
a = [1, 4, 35, 40, 56, 70, 90, 110 ]
b = [3, 20, 39, 57, 62, 84, 100, 150]

ia = 0
ib = 0
best_at = -1
best_diff = 10000
while ia < len(a) and ib < len(b):
    delta = a[ia] - b[ib]
    if abs(delta) <= 15:        
        print("Found match at ia={} ({}) and ib={} ({})".format(ia,  a[ia], ib, b[ib]))
        if abs(delta) < best_diff:
            best_at = ib
            best_diff = abs(delta)                   
        if delta < 0:
            if best_diff < 10000:
                print("Best match for {} is {} at ib={}".format(a[ia], b[best_at], best_at))
                best_diff = 10000
            ia += 1            
        elif delta > 0:
            ib += 1
        else:
            # perfect match
            print("Best match for {} is {} at ib={}".format(a[ia], b[best_at], best_at))
            best_diff = 10000
            ia += 1
            ib += 1

    elif delta > 15:
        ib += 1
    elif delta < -15:
        if best_diff < 10000:
            print("Best match for {} is {} at ib={}".format(a[ia], b[best_at], best_at))
            best_diff = 10000
        ia += 1
```

This still runs in linear time. The time complexity is roughly O(n+m), where n is the length of list `a` and m is the length of list `b`, and you can easily see that's the case because in every iteration through the while loop, either `ia` or `ib` gets advanced by 1.

I don't think you can do better than O(n+m) if you want to find the closest match for every timestamp in list a.